# C - My scanf never stops taking inputs

Tags: c, for-loop, compilation, scanf, factorial

So, I was messing around a little bit with loops when I thought it would be a nice idea to try and make a simple factorials calculator. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{   
    int num;
    int ans;

    printf("Enter any number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    ans = num;

    for (int i = (num-1); i = 1; --i)
    {
        ans *= i;

    }
    printf("%d! is %d \n", num, ans);

    return 0;
}
```

Pretty straightforward. My problem is, however, that when I have to enter a number, for example 5, the scanf just never stops. Instead of moving forward with the execution, it keeps allowing me to enter more numbers after I press enter. In fact it never stops, I could be adding numbers for hours without it running at all. Any idea why this is?

I did a desk check with 5! and it worked, but I can't possibly get it to compile, at all.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have i = 1 in the loop condition?

Comment: The compiler should have warned you with *"somename.c:13:29: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]"*. Did you not see that warning?

Comment: There was absolutely no warning at all. There wasn't anything, since I wasn't able to run the program at all after the compiler read the printf. That was the mistake however. Thanks!

Comment: Probably because you didn't use -Wall.

Comment: When you ran the program in the debugger, didn't you see that it was going into the `for` statement and looping forever? Why did you think it was stuck in `scanf`?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int num;
   int ans;

   printf("Enter number: ");
   scanf(" %d", &num);

   ans = num;

   for(int i = (num - 1); i > 1; --i)
      ans = ans * i;

   printf("%d! is %d\n", num, ans);

   return 0;
}
```

**Modifications:**

1. Changed `i = 1` to `i > 1` in for loop condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem was the condition like you pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the `scanf()` but the `for` loop which never stops because you are assigning `1` to `i` in the `for` loop condition:

```
for (int i = (num-1); i = 1; --i)
                      ^^^^^
```

`for` loop evaluate the condition before executing the body of the loop and the condition `i = 1` will always evaluate to `true`. After executing the loop body, the `i` is decremented and then the condition is evaluated again which assigns `1` to `i`. Hence, the loop ends up executing infinitely.

Change the `for` loop condition to `i > 1`:

```
for (int i = (num-1); i > 1; --i)
```